# DELPHI OPENCV : SURF detection against a database

Tags: database, delphi, opencv, pascal

I am an OpenCv newbie,and i just want to built something like this example :
[OPENCV: SURF detection against a database of 20000 images](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbYDjBa3Lyk)

I just want to know what are the steps to follow to achieve this, i managed to integrate **OpenCv 2.4.13** with **Delphi Berlin 10.1**.

It seems to be working i even tried some examples that i found here : https://github.com/Laex/Delphi-OpenCV

Basically what i wanna do is realtime detection against a database, using a webcam as shown in the previous video.

Comment: Ok, that seems nice.... But what's your question?

Comment: I just want to know what are the steps to follow to achieve this.

Comment: Get the images from the database, convert to a suitable image format if necessary, then run opencv on it.